# Accessing an Array List contents in a different class

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array list of card objects `hand` in one class. This array list `hand` HAS to stay private. In a different class, I need to access the Card objects within this array list and call a `toString()` method on each of them to convert them to readable card names. So I created a `getHand()` method in the class that contains the array list `hand` that returns hand. But how do I now access the individual cards within the hand? Because if I do `hand.get(i).getSuit()` for instance, it can't do that because `hand` is private. Any advice is appreciated.

Class A:

```
private ArrayList<Card> hand; 

public Player()
{       
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
}
    ...
```

Class B:

```
...
public String toString(){
    this.getSuit();
    this.getValue();
    //code to convert numerical suit and value to a string
    //this method will use a Card object
    //as an implicit parameter
```

Class C:

```
Player p = new Player();
p.getHand();
//next I need to indicate that each card
//within hand needs to be called with
//the toString method? This is my question
```

Comment: And did You try to do it like You described ?, just instead of `hand` use `getHand()`

Comment: I don't know why you can't do that, also don't know why you use a local variable `hand` in the constructor of `Player`

Answer (score 0):

`p.getHand()` will return the `ArrayList<Card>` so you only have to iterate through it and print `.toString()` of each Card object

```
Player p = new Player();
ArrayList<Card> cards = p.getHand();

for (Card card : cards)
{
    System.out.println(card.toString());
}
```

You have to call `getHand()` instead of using `ArrayList` directly because `getHand()` is public getter and other class can call it but `hand` is private and it will be only accessed inside of ClassA without using any getter or setter.

Also, your `Player` constructor should look like this

```
public Player()
{       
    this.hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to avoid returning the member variable of the Player class (this is a breach of the Law of Demeter).

Here are some alternatives:

```
class Player implements Iterable<Card> {
    ...
    public Iterator<Card> iterator() {
        return cards.iterator();
    }
    ...
}
```

Another option:

```
interface CardVisitor {
    public void visitCard(Card card);
}

class Player {
    ...
    public void visitCards(CardVisitor visitor) {
        for (Card card : cards)
            visitor.visitCard(card);
    }
    ...
}

class CardPrinter {
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ...
        CardVisitor visitor = new CardVisitor() {
            public void visitCard(Card card) {
                sb.append(card.toString()); // or something like that
            }
        }
        player.visitCards(visitor);
        ...
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

There are many more ways to go about this, but I guess you're getting my point.